# java- output different random strings

Tags: java, string, random

I am new to java and I am struck with my progress.

I have a method that generates a random string between 1-13 and the 'cdsh'.Combine those two together and it will determine the card type that I will received in my program.

I will random it four times and if there is any results the same, 
the program will random again.

```
 e.g random output 
    s1(spades of 1)
    h3(hearts of 3)
    s1(spades of 1) <-- duplicated! it will random again and produce and different string.
    d1(diamond of 1)
```

---

```
public static String randomizedCard() {
    int randomInt;
    String rank = null;
    String suits = null;
    String cardType; 
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();  
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(13);

    if(randomInt == 0)
    {
    randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(13);
    }

    rank = Integer.toString(randomInt);

    char[] chars = "cdhs".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random randomChar = new Random();

    char c = chars[randomChar.nextInt(chars.length)];
    sb.append(c);
    suits = sb.toString();

    cardType = suits + rank;
    System.out.println(cardType);
    return cardType;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {    

        String[] ic = new String[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            /*from here onwards I get confused on how should I write the code such that
              if it randoms the same string, it will the random method (randomizedCard)
              till it produce all four different random numbers without duplicate and store
              it into the array.*/                  

            //store the random string to an array
            ic[i] = randomizedCard();
            // if it's the same random again 
            if(ic[i] == randomsizedCard()) {
                randomsizedCard();
                ic[i] = randomsizedCard();
            }

        }          
    }
```

How should I write the code such that if it randoms the same string, it will the random method (randomizedCard) till it produce all four different random numbers without duplicate and store it into the array?

Comment: Looks like the actual question is in a comment in the second code section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your randomly generated cards into an ArrayList, and then check each new card against the others.

```
ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList();
while (cards.size() < 4) {
    String card = randomizedCard();
    if (!cards.contains(card)) {
        cards.add(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is valid but involves a lot of creating and then throwing away of objects. There are constant-time approaches that are more predictable.

Answer (score 4):

For this sort of thing there is a much simpler way:

Create a `List<Card> cards`;

Fill the list with every possible card:

```
for (String suit: suites) {
    for (int i=1;i<=13;i++) {
        cards.add(new Card(suit, i));
    }
}
```

Then shuffle the list:

```
Collections.shuffle(cards);
```

Now just take the first X items out of the list and you are guaranteed that each one is both random and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the card has allready been created and if so, create others until you have 4.

```
List<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();
while ( cards.size() < 4 )
{
     String newCard = randomizedCard();
     if ( !cards.contains( newCard ) )
     {
           cards.add( newCard );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well random is random.

If you want random without repetition, do it like this.

Create a Card object

```
public class Card {
    int seed;//0-3, the card seed 
    int number;//1-10 the card number
    public Card(seed, number) {
        this.seed =seed;
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String toString() {
       return "card " + number + " of " + seed; //here you convert from int to beautiful seed name
    }
}
```

create all the card in a deck into a collection

```
LinkedList deck = new LinkedList();
for (int seed = 0; seed<4; seed++)     for (int number = 1; number<11; number++) { 
  deck.add(new Card(seed,number));
}
```

[shuffle the cards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

```
Collections.shuffle(deck);
```

pick the first four using the [pop mechanism (return and remove one)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#pop%28%29):

```
System.out.println(deck.pop());
System.out.println(deck.pop());
System.out.println(deck.pop());
System.out.println(deck.pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getString(int x){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("*******Add your string here****** ");
    list.add("*******Add your string here****** ");

    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        hashMap.put( i, list.get(i));
    }

    return hashMap.get(x);
 }
```

In the main function call the `getString()` with arguments 0,1,2... which returns the string randomly without repetition.